# pgfplots: shadow for markers

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I was wondering if it's possible to add shadows to markers within pgfplots. I tried the `circular drop shadow` option (from TikZ) which unfortunately had no effect at all. I also read that one can define custom marker styles with `\pgfdeclareplotmark` but that's way beyond my PGF knowledge.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\pgfplotsset{%
  mystyle/.style={red,mark=*,mark options={fill=white,circular drop shadow}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
     \addplot[mystyle] {x^2 - x + 4};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Am I missing the easy solution (disregarding that nothing about shadows is mentioned in the pgfplots manual) or do I have to get deeper into PGF?

Comment: I wonder why you'd want to do this. The entire point of a plot it to present data in a clear way, and I don't see that shadows really contribute.

Comment: I would assume that the shadows lib relies on high-level tikz paths. However, plot marks are drawn using the more efficient pgf basic layer. Perhaps this makes a difference... what happens if you try `mark=ball` (which is the only marker using high-level tikz paths)?

Comment: @JosephWright I thought exactly the same... It's just that I only have a few points which are compared to a empirical formula und they look a little bit lost.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Changing the marker type to ball doesn't have any effect...

Comment: Ok. Seems as if adding shadows requires more insight (as you feared). One way to do it might be to declare a plot mark and use `\draw[circular drop shadow] \pgfextra{ <lowlevel marker code as before>};` as marker path expression. This could work (I do not know). In any way, it seems to be more involved - perhaps even without an easy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this works:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{*)}
{%
\fill[drop shadow={draw=black,fill=black,opacity=.25,shadow xshift=2pt,shadow
yshift=-2pt}] (0,0) circle [radius=2pt];
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
     \addplot[red,mark=*)] {x^2 - x + 4};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It seems that it is ok to use regular tikz code inside `\pgfdeclareplotmark`.
It may be horribly wrong, though, and could break any number of other things,
so please use it with caution.

Comment: Plot marks are drawn after the plotting path... I would hope that all is right. In my opinion, it is the only promising approach.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I wasn't aware of the fact that it's possible to use TikZ code inside the `\pgfdeclareplotmark`. Although I would recommend the solution from Christian: `\pgfdeclareplotmark{mymark}{\draw[circular drop shadow={draw=black!50}] \pgfextra{\pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfplotmarksize}};}`. This leads to – at least for circular markers – much nicer shadows. It's also not perfect because the `draw=black!50` just yields nice results for standard opacity. Setting `opacity=0.5` requires the draw color to be set at `black!25`. Somehow logical but not very handy...

Comment: As I'm new to this site: is it usual to edit nearly perfect answers to accept them or shall I create a new one?

Comment: I see, the marks created with `circular drop shadow` will only show up correctly in adobe reader, not in other viewers.  That's why they did not work for me. I tried the Christian's suggestion, but as I normally do not use adobe reader, they looked really bad.